# Insert Data from Table A to Table B WHERE (conditions) & SET Col.a = "xxx"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, insert-into

```
| Table [A]                          | Table [B]   
----------------------               ---------------------
|                                    |
| id    value   data                 | id    value   data
| ab     15      100                 | ac     19      200
| ab     18      101                 | ac     28      310
| ab     22      199                 | ac     39      401
```

Table A is my old database table with history data.
Table B is my current database table with corrected value in id

I'll like to insert historic data from Table A into Table B WHERE value<=xxxx AND value >=xxxx and also at the same time set the data from tablea.id = ac when inserted into Table B so the data outcome will be.

```
| Table [A]                          | Table [B]   
--------------------                 ----------------------
|                                    |
| id    value   data                 | id    value   data
| ab     15      100                 | ac     19      200
| ab     18      101                 | ac     28      310
| ab     22      199                 | ac     39      401
|                                    | ac     15      100
|                                    | ac     18      101
|                                    | ac     22      199
```

I'll be using INSERT IGNORE as my table has 3 column as it's composite primary key. Table description is just a sample. My table has alot more columns just highlighting the main difference for the data import I want to accomplish.

Comment: Will the id  be always `ac`? and i guess 6th column  in table [b] ,the value should be `18` instead of `28`

Comment: For this current import yes the value will be ac.

Comment: Then you can use the below Gordon Solution

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into tableb (id, value, data)
    select 'ac', value, data
    from tablea
    where id = 'ab';
```

This inserts the values and changes the `id` from `'ab'` to `'ac'`.

Comment: I've tried but received an error code: 1054. Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
http://pastebin.com/PwTxc9Ga

Comment: @Royston . . . The sample data in your question has columns called `id` in both tables.  I don't know why it would be undefined.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! It works no idea why would the columns would have that field "id" when I copied it directly from the MySQL Workbench.